# Extracting subset of the data frame in R

Tags: r

Suppose I read a csv file into a data frame called "d". I wish to print the last 2 rows of this data frame. I tried the below but it is printing all the content starting from n-1. Can someone help me understand this behavior please?

```
> n<-nrow(d)
> n
[1] 153
> subset(d[n:n-1,])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use tail

```
  tail(d, 2)
```

Will give the last two rows.

Answer (score 7):

@mnel is correct that using tail() would probably be the easiest, however I think that your confusion has to do with how subset() and indexing work in general. In your example be mindful of how you index matrices and data.frames since

```
d[(n:n - 1), ]
```

is not the same as

```
d[n:(n-1), ]
```

so check the difference carefully since the order of operations are important to understand.
The subset() function also indexes based on a logical indicator and has the form

```
 subset(object, subset = logicalvector)
```

where the logical vector gives the rows that you want to extract. See ?subset for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me ...

```
d <- matrix(1:10,nrow=5)
d
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

d <- as.data.frame(d)
d
  V1 V2
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9
5  5 10

n <- nrow(d)
> n
[1] 5
d[n:(n-1),] ## Specifying the number of the row inside the brackets.
 V1 V2
5  5 10
4  4  9

d[n:n-1,] ## without brackets it will do 5:5 -1 = 4, so printing only the fourth row
  V1 V2
4  4  9
```

Comment: No need for subset here. You are using [.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:
   `tail(d, 2)` 
or 
    `d[(n-1):n, ]`
Hope it helps